# Send get request with alamofire in swift

Tags: node.js, swift, get, request, alamofire

When I send a request, the request is sent, but the parameter I send is not recognized on the server
‌But in postman the request is okay and works fine

this is my response in client side : 'country is required'

this is my server side code (nodejs-express) :

```
const app = express()
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
    app.use(expressvalidator())
    app.get('/cities', (req, res) => {
        req.checkBody('country', 'country is required').notEmpty()
        let errors = req.validationErrors()
        if (errors) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                message: errors[0].msg
            })
        }
        var cities = require('country-city').getCities(req.body.country);
        console.log(cities)
        return res.json({ cities: cities })
    })
```

and my client side code(swift) :

```
let params2 : Parameters = ["country" : "China"]
    Alamofire.request("http://172.20.10.3:4000/cities",method : .get, parameters: params2, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (jsonData) in
        do {
            print(jsonData)
        }catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it server side? What does the request look like in the server?

Comment: server side is okey my friend . when i change both side method to post works fine but in get client side has problem @RenzoTissoni

Comment: Not what I meant by that. By seeing the request from the server side you might find if (and possibly how) the request from the client is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use URLEncoding.default the data will be added in the URL, to create a JSON with the parameters you set you have to use the option JSONEncoding.default.